# Why doesn't the compiler raise a warning when a struct member is unread?

Tags: struct, rust, unused-variables

I have these 2 pieces of code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: int = 5;
    x = 6;
    println!("value {}", x);
}
```

With this code, the compiler will raise warning:

> the value is never read at `let x: int = 5`

But with the following code, the compiler doesn't.

```
struct Point {
    x: int,
    y: int,
}
fn main() {
    let mut p = Point {x: 1i, y: 2i};
    p.x = 5;
    println!("value {}, {}", p.x, p.y);
}
```

Why does that happens? We never read the value when `x = 1i`. Rather, we read the value at `x = 5i`. So why the compiler doesn't raise warning like the code before?

Answer (score 2):

I think this happens because the compiler only analyzes immediate local variables and does not go deeper into structures. I imagine that full analysis would require a rather complex algorithm, and there is little need for it.

Or maybe it is a bug in the compiler, or, more likely, an unimplemented feature. You can submit a ticket to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/) if you think it is important.

Comment: Nah, not a bug, just something that hasn’t been implemented to the fullest extent imaginable.

Comment: I probably didn't express myself correctly. Under "bug" I meant exactly an unimplemented feature.